# How to create slanting SVG Image with slanting text

Tags: pdf, svg, svg-filters, svg-animate, pdfmake

I am trying yo create the slanting Image in svg with slanting text as shown in below Image

[image]

I have tried to create same format but not able to create exact design as display in overall text, you can also see that down horizontal is attached with below column.

Please find my below code

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="30" style="fill:grey;"  transform="rotate(30 20,40)" /> 
<style> .textColor {  fill: white; } </style> 
<text x="50" y="25" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12" class="textColor" stroke-width="0" dy=".3em"  transform="rotate(30 20,40)">overall</text> 
</svg>
```

please find below image created with this svg, where the red portion is there I also want grey color over there, Im short i want exact image as shown in upper image.

[image]

I need to do this in [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html), Copy this below code and paste on left section screen in PDFMake site, I need to display exact layout as display in 1st Image

```
var dd = {
    content: [

        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                body: [
                    ['OverAll', 'Operational', 'Solvency'],
                    ['1', '1', '1']
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw whatever you want with it. You can examine the markup it produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to skew the rectangle. If you rotate the text and the rectangle 50 degs the skew angle should be -90+50 = -40. Please note that I've added a viewBox to the svg since by skewing and rotating the rect part of it was moved outside the svg elelent.

Probably the best solution to your problem (Robert Longson's comment) would be drawing a polygon in an svg editor instead of the rect.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="140" height="100" viewBox="-20 0 120 80">
<rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="30" style="fill:grey;"  transform="rotate(50 20,40) skewX(-40)" /> 
<style> .textColor {  fill: white; } </style> 
<text x="50" y="25" text-anchor="middle" dx="-10" font-size="12" class="textColor" stroke-width="0"  transform="rotate(50 20,40)">overall</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: so in table case if we put avg header as you answered in that case would the down column can be arranged as you see in 1st image?

Comment: Updated the question, do you have any idea of PDFMake

Comment: can you check for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465940/table-header-as-svg-image